# imap_open(): Couldn't open stream in core php

Tags: php

There is issue occured on email parsing.
I am using imap.
error occured as `{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}` INBOX
How to solved this issue.
Its working on localhost, facing issue in production server.

Comment: maybe show us the code?

Comment: $inbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX'',$email,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

I think issue occured on host name.